# CPU and memory utilization within the date and time given

Tags: sql-server

Is that any query to get previous date CPU utilization and memory usage within the timeline, example 02/10/2017 (8 PM) until 03/10/2017 (1 AM) .Thanks a lot.

Comment: Generally, no. You need a monitoring tool to collect and store this information for you.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to retrieve historical information would be some monitoring software but there is a bit of information you could get from the ring buffer (assuming you're on a somewhat recent version of SQL Server).

For example CPU load you could get with this query [taken from Glenn Berry's dmv queries](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/sql-server-diagnostic-information-queries-for-september-2017/)

```
-- Get CPU Utilization History for last 256 minutes (in one minute intervals)  (Query 36) (CPU Utilization History)
DECLARE @ts_now bigint = (SELECT cpu_ticks/(cpu_ticks/ms_ticks) FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info WITH (NOLOCK)); 

SELECT TOP(256) SQLProcessUtilization AS [SQL Server Process CPU Utilization], 
               SystemIdle AS [System Idle Process], 
               100 - SystemIdle - SQLProcessUtilization AS [Other Process CPU Utilization], 
               DATEADD(ms, -1 * (@ts_now - [timestamp]), GETDATE()) AS [Event Time] 
FROM (SELECT record.value('(./Record/@id)[1]', 'int') AS record_id, 
            record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)[1]', 'int') 
            AS [SystemIdle], 
            record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization)[1]', 'int') 
            AS [SQLProcessUtilization], [timestamp] 
      FROM (SELECT [timestamp], CONVERT(xml, record) AS [record] 
            FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE ring_buffer_type = N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR' 
            AND record LIKE N'%<SystemHealth>%') AS x) AS y 
ORDER BY record_id DESC OPTION (RECOMPILE);
------
```

Or something like this query from  [Jonathan Kehayias](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/identifying-external-memory-pressure-with-dm_os_ring_buffers-and-ring_buffer_resource_monitor/) to look at recent memory pressure:

```
–System Memory Usage
SELECT 
    EventTime,
    record.value('(/Record/ResourceMonitor/Notification)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as [Type],
    record.value('(/Record/ResourceMonitor/IndicatorsProcess)[1]', 'int') as [IndicatorsProcess],
    record.value('(/Record/ResourceMonitor/IndicatorsSystem)[1]', 'int') as [IndicatorsSystem],
    record.value('(/Record/MemoryRecord/AvailablePhysicalMemory)[1]', 'bigint') AS [Avail Phys Mem, Kb],
    record.value('(/Record/MemoryRecord/AvailableVirtualAddressSpace)[1]', 'bigint') AS [Avail VAS, Kb]
FROM (
    SELECT
        DATEADD (ss, (-1 * ((cpu_ticks / CONVERT (float, ( cpu_ticks / ms_ticks ))) – [timestamp])/1000), GETDATE()) AS EventTime,
        CONVERT (xml, record) AS record
    FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers
    CROSS JOIN sys.dm_os_sys_info
    WHERE ring_buffer_type = 'RING_BUFFER_RESOURCE_MONITOR') AS tab
ORDER BY EventTime DESC;
```

None of those will let you select a timeframe that surpasses the data stored in the ring buffer though, so I would still recommend getting some monitoring software but variations on those queries might give you a little bit of insight in what the load was "recently".